# CMake does not find MPI when using a legacy fortran compiler version

Tags: cmake, fortran, mpi, archlinux, openmpi

Yesterday I asked a rather similar question. But this one is slightly different.

I am on Arch Linux with gcc 10 installed. I need to use gcc with version < 9 (a colleague even uses gcc4) to compile a Fortran code base.

So I installed the gcc7-fortran package because this colleague told me that it once worked with this compiler.
CMake figures out that it has to use mpif90 to compile the whole project which does not call gfortran-7 but gfortran which is version 10.

I could not yet figure out how to tell mpif90 to use another compiler as gfortran. So i did a little hack: I moved /usr/bin/gfortran to /usr/bin/gfortran-10 and made a soft link from /usr/bin/gfortran-7 to /usr/bin/gfortran. Now mpif90 uses gfortran with version 7. Great.

Now here comes the error. CMake **is** able to find MPI if I use gfortran-10 as compiler but **is not** able to find MPI if I use gfortran-7.

```
-- Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing: MPI_Fortran_WORKS)                                      
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message): 
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_Fortran_FOUND) (found version "3.1")                         
Call Stack (most recent call first):                                                            
  /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  CMAKE/modules/FindMPI.cmake:1721 (find_package_handle_standard_args)                          
  CMakeLists.txt:388 (find_package)
```

Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

when using gfortran-10 cmake tells finding MPI with this message

```
-- Found MPI_Fortran: /usr/lib/openmpi/libmpi_usempif08.so (found version "3.1")
```

Comment: Are you sure your MPI library is compatible with both gcc-7 and gcc-10? You may well need separate libraries compiled up appropriately. This is why things such as http://modules.sourceforge.net/ exist

Comment: No I am not sure. And it seems it is not. However I have no idea how to install an older version of openmpi other than downloading /  building it by hand. So maybe I could try this. (Seems like a noob question now)

Comment: Assuming `cmake` tries `use mpi` or `use mpi_f08`, the test will use Fortran `mod` files ... that are not interoperable between different `gfortran` version. Bottom like, your hack cannot work and you first need to rebuild MPI with the Fortran compiler you will be using.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. I come from the C++ world and at there (my level of knowledgment) everything should be backward-compatible. So I assumed the gcc compiler collection can do this in every language it supports.